# flutter webview 4.x.x , navigating backwords doesn't work

Tags: flutter, webview

i am using `flutter webview version 4.4.2,` page displays. if i load `foo.com` and then click on some link ex. `foo.com/about` it works but when i press back from `foo.com/about` app closes, while it should not close instead app should display `foo.com`,

This is my full code:

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final _controller = WebViewController()
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(websiteURL));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(appTitle)),
        body: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller));
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!